# Android unable to create mediaplayer

Tags: android, media-player

i play a sound with this code:

```
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Start.this, R.raw.music);   
                mp.start();
                NameButton.setEnabled(false);
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        mp.release();
                        NameButton.setEnabled(true);
                    }

                });
```

It plays well. I modified the length of the file with Audacity, and now eclipse and my phone force closes.

```
06-05 07:16:20.106: ERROR/MediaPlayer(427): Unable to to create media player
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427): create failed:
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:645)
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427):     at com.bfarago.clickme.Start$1.onClick(Start.java:108)
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(427):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 07:16:20.126: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(427): Shutting down VM
```

I don't know what the problem can be. Is it possible that Android cannot play very short sounds (it's like 1/10 sec now)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "modified the length of the file with Audacity". What exactly was done? and what type of an audio file is it?

Comment: Hi! I deleted some part of the audio file. If you know Audacity, you know easy is can be done. Type is .mp3. My guess is that during the cut the file has been damaged some way or something..

Comment: I am guessing the same thing, you can try playing the clip on your pc to check if it is okay :)

Comment: did you find solution?